# Parsing Date with a Zone in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

i've tried looking here and there in stack but my code won't work.

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Date d = getInitialTerminationTime("2015-03-19T14:26:45.704Z","yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    }
    public static Date getInitialTerminationTime(String dateString,String dateFormat){

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);//"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
        Date date=null;
        try
        {
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString); 
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return date; 
    }
```

As u can see, basically i can't parse the format "2015-03-19T14:26:45.704Z".
How can i amend this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your pattern from

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

to

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSX
```

where the `X` represents a [ISO 8601 timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)

> For parsing, "Z" is parsed as the UTC time zone designator.

This is all assuming you wanted `Z` to represent Zulu.